# Rendering a template using Gulp, Nunjucks, and an Array

Tags: javascript, gulp, nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

I have some html like this:

```
<code class="html">
      <div class="u-color-background-gray-100">
        <code>u-color-background-gray-100</code>
      </div>

      <div class="u-color-background-gray-300">
        <code>u-color-background-gray-300</code>
      </div>
</code>
```

I would like to render it using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [gulp-nunjucks-render](https://github.com/carlosl/gulp-nunjucks-render), and the array `['100', '300']`.

## ANSWER

This is the answer - but I'd like the give the credit to the person who helped me refine the question, pointed out the right components, and helped me with the syntax - so please officially answer it - and I will remove this inline answer - I have tested the below):

```
<code class="html">
   {% for item in ['100', '300'] %}
      <div class="u-color-background-gray-{{item}}>
        <code>u-color-background-gray-{{item}}</code>
      </div>
   {% endfor %}
</code>
```

Comment: With gulp, [gulp-nunjucks-render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nunjucks-render) is one of my favorite. For document see [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly but it should be something like `class="u-color-background-gray-{{item}}"`.